# Condensing successive matrix rotations into one matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to know how to condense multiple rotation transformation matrices into one.

I am performing three successive rotations on vector V.
First, I transform V about the Z-axis by angle $\theta_Y$, yielding vector A.
Second, I transform vector A about the X-axis by angle $\theta_X$, yielding vector B.
Third, I transform the vector B about the Y-axis by angle $\theta_Y$, yielding the final vector that I want, C.  $R_Z$ is first, $R_X$ is second, and $R_Y$ is last

$$A = R_Z(\theta_Z) V = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_Z) & \sin(\theta_Z) & 0 \\ -\sin(\theta_Z) & \cos(\theta_Z) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\  \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B = R_X(\theta_X) A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos(\theta_X) & \sin(\theta_X)\\ 0 & -\sin(\theta_X) & \cos(\theta_X) \\  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$C = R_Y(\theta_Y)B = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_Y) & 0 & -\sin(\theta_Y) \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \sin(\theta_Y) & 0 & \cos(\theta_Y) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

I am doing these transformation separately, but I want to condense the computation.  I cant find an explanation of how to condense more than one rotation matrices into one.

I want 
     (1) AN expression for a rotation matrix that is a combination of $R(\theta_Z)$ and $R(\theta_X)$, call it $R_{ZX}$, which takes vector V and transforms it directly to vector B without the intermediate calculation of vector A and (2) an expression for a rotation matrix that does all transformations in one step (call it $R_{XYZ}$) that transforms V directly to C.

Comment: Multiplying rotation matrices results in a rotation matrix.  Your single matrix would be the multiplication of all 3 or your rotations.  You'll just might have some large terms in the single matrix since you have three different angle variables $\theta_X$, $\theta_Y$, and $\theta_Z$.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Multiplication)

Comment: @Carser But in what order do I multiply the rotation matrices? I know that it is not commutative.  Do I first find the product RZX of RZ and RX (with RZ on the left and RX on the right) and then multiply that by RY (with RZX on the left ad RY on the right)?

Comment: Oh right, it is not commutative.  If your order of rotation is $ZXY$, then the multiplication would be $R_Y R_X R_Z$.  Just out of curiosity, why did you choose $ZXY$?

Comment: If your issue is more or less connected with [Euler angles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html), note that a general rotation doesn't necessitate to use a matrix of the form "C", it is of the form $ABA'$where $A'$ has the same form as $A$, with a different angle in general.

Answer (score 3):

Your rotation matrix $R$ is given by
$$
      R = R_Y R_X R_Z
$$
or
$$
R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_Y) & 0 & -\sin(\theta_Y) \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \sin(\theta_Y) & 0 & \cos(\theta_Y) \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos(\theta_X) & \sin(\theta_X)\\ 0 & -\sin(\theta_X) & \cos(\theta_X) \\  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_Z) & \sin(\theta_Z) & 0 \\ -\sin(\theta_Z) & \cos(\theta_Z) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\  \end{bmatrix}
$$
You'll notice that the order of the multiplication is reversed from the order of rotation.

An observation: the rotations you have given about the axes seem to be using "left-hand" rotation has opposed to "right-hand."  There's nothing wrong with that but I'm used to seeing rotations that follow the right-hand rule, which would just swap the signs on the sines to give you
$$
R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_Y) & 0 & \sin(\theta_Y) \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -\sin(\theta_Y) & 0 & \cos(\theta_Y) \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos(\theta_X) & -\sin(\theta_X)\\ 0 & \sin(\theta_X) & \cos(\theta_X) \\  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_Z) & -\sin(\theta_Z) & 0 \\ \sin(\theta_Z) & \cos(\theta_Z) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Suppose, that I would like to rotate the vector $(0,0,1)$ to $(1,1,1)$, how should I do this? I tried $R_Z(\frac{\pi}{4}) \cdot R_Y(\frac{\pi}{4}) \cdot R_X(\frac{\pi}{4})$ and  $R_X(\frac{\pi}{4}) \cdot R_Y(\frac{\pi}{4}) \cdot R_Z(\frac{\pi}{4})$ (rotation by 45 degrees) both of them seem not work.

Comment: @AlexanderCska, are you sure this is the rotation you are applying?  You can't rotate (0,0,1) to (1,1,1), as those two vectors have different magnitude.  You maybe mean that you want to rotate (0,0,1) to the direction of the vector (1,1,1), but you can do that with only two rotations, you don't need three.